# ionic 3 audio livestreaming is slower than the live radio station streaming

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am developing a radio station mobile app with ionic3 and after integrating the livestreaming using the StreamingMedia pluging in ionic3 is 1-minute slower than the radio station main streaming, please any help ?

Radio.ts

```
 export class RadioPlayer {
  url:string;
  stream:any;
  promise:any;
   constructor() {
   this.url = "http://104.247.79.188:8000/kfm";
   this.stream = new Audio(this.url);
 };
 play() {
   this.stream.play();
   this.promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     this.stream.addEventListener('playing', () => {
       resolve(true);
     });
    this.stream.addEventListener('error', () => {
       reject(false);
     });
   });
  return this.promise;
};
pause() {
  this.stream.pause();
};

}
```

appComponent.ts

```
 import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { Platform, MenuController, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
 import {RadioPlayer} from './radio/radio';
    @Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [RadioPlayer]
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(player: RadioPlayer) 
{
    this.player = player;
    this.play();
 }
 play() {
    this.player.play().then(() => {
      console.log('Playing');
    });
  }
  pause() {
    this.player.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some of your `code`?

Comment: radio.ts  export class RadioPlayer {
  url:string;
  stream:any;
  promise:any;
  
 constructor() {
   this.url = "/*9";
   this.stream = new Audio(this.url);
 };

 play() {
   this.stream.play();
   this.promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     this.stream.addEventListener('playing', () => {
       resolve(true);
     });

     this.stream.addEventListener('error', () => {
       reject(false);
     });
   });
   
  return this.promise;
};

pause() {
  this.stream.pause();
};

}

Comment: Can you read it? Please put that inside your question with `code` formatting?

Comment: Sorry for that, that is code above

Comment: Are you using this plugin?: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/

Comment: yes i added the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to use [**Native Streaming Media**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media/) plugin.Since it is native hope your slowness will vanish.

> This plugin allows you to stream audio and video in a fullscreen,
>   native player on iOS and Android.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-streaming-media
npm install --save @ionic-native/streaming-media
```

[**Git Repo**](https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media)

Comment: is not working,please can you help me with a sample code

Comment: is working now, I disable the  orientation: 'false ' but is not working on android

Comment: the audio streaming i want is not in a fullscreen, and when i disable the fullscreen in streaming-media plugin is not working. please any help